# Помогите разобраться с simplexml

Tags: xml, php

Добрый день. Разбираюсь с simplexml, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Предположим есть xml-файл следующего содержания (a_xml.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stat>
  <user>
    <cart>13</cart>
    <subid>2</subid>
  </user>

  <user>  
    <cart>54</cart>
    <subid>-</subid>
  </user>
</stat>
```

И есть такой же простой php-код:

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file('a_xml.xml');
foreach($xml->stat->user as $user) {
  echo $user->cart;
}
?>
```

И в этом момент я ожидаю на экране увидеть числа 13 и 54. Но на деле выходит: "**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**". Почему так происходит? Где ошибка?

И самое странное для меня то, что если в xml-файле сделать изменение небольшое, а именно поместить тег `<stat>` внутрь тега `<rss>`, то есть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss>
<stat>
  <user>
    <cart>13</cart>
    <subid>2</subid>
  </user>

  <user>  
    <cart>54</cart>
    <subid>-</subid>
  </user>
</stat>
</rss>
```

То всё замечательно работает, на экране появляется желаемый результат. Но естественно меня такой выход из проблемы не устраивает. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Стандарт `XML` подразумевает обязательное наличие одного `root-`элемента. В первом случае его роль играет `stat`, во втором `rss`. Метод `simplexml_load_file` возвращает объект, который как раз и является `root-`элементом.
- Поэтому, когда вы делаете `$xml = simplexml_load_file`, то, `$xml` по сути уже является представлением вашего `$stat`, а это означает что `$xml->stat` - это пустая коллекция элементов.

> Для решения задачи в первом случае *(без дополнительного уровня вложенности `rss`)* достаточно использовать `foreach($xml->user as $user)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, первый, базовый элемент( stat ) можно вовсе опустить, так как XML-парсер достаточно умен, чтобы найти корень DOM-модели XML документа.

Answer (score 0):

Вам можно заюзать обычный FOR-цикл, опираясь на это:

```
echo $xml->user[0]->cart;  //13

echo $xml->user[1]->cart; //54
```